# Wordpress post edit page reloads on JS button click in custom metabox

Tags: javascript, wordpress, meta-boxes

I have a custom metabox for all edit-post webpages.
This metabox contains table with each row containing an image tag and a edit and delete button to delete that image or update it from media library.
Now,

When I click the Delete button,
the js code that runs is :

```
jQuery('#delete_image').on('click',function(){
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

But, when I click the delete button in metabox, the **page reloads**, instead of deleting the row.
Please help on how to approach this.

Also tried :

> > - event.preventDefault() but no change in behaviour.
> > - Disabling all plugins (i'm using chrome)

Answer (score 0):

maybe an event is already on this element try with .off to delete other listener
and return false to stop propagation.

```
jQuery('#delete_image').off().on('click',function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    return false
});
```

Comment: thanks bormat.. tried this but still the page is reloading.. also tried changing the id of the button but no success

Comment: If you dont add listener, I suppose nothing is happen but can you confirm it.

Comment: can you try these 2 alternatives :jQuery('#delete_image').off().on('click',function(){
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    if(!$tr[0]) alert('tr not found');
    $tr.remove();
    return false;
});
                  and 
jQuery('#delete_image').off().on('click',function(){
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    if(!$tr[0]) alert('tr not found');
    $tr.hide();
    return false;
});

Comment: why are you using jQuery instead of $ if you use $ in the listener, try with only jQuery ?

Comment: Coz it says $ not found. Well thanks for your time and help... but the upper solutions didn't work

Comment: Yes but you don't answer what happen if you don't add listener, is the page still reload ? can you put an alert in your listener at the end to see if the code is executed

Comment: hi bormat, if you don't add listener, its still reloading.

Comment: you use id witch works only once think about using class, or an alternative not the best is jQuery("* #delete_image").off().on('click',function(){
    jQuery(this).closest('tr').remove();alert();
    return false;
}); if you have no alert the selector is false.

Comment: check the selector in console jQuery("* #delete_image")

Comment: gives [input type="submit" id="delete_image" value="Delete"]

Comment: if you put your mousse on the result the element is hightlight in chrome and you can check it is the one you want. you dont tell me if replace your selector by  jQuery("* #delete_image") solve the problem

Comment: jQuery('* #delete_image').off().on('click',function(e){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});